# Как построена иерархия категорий в авито?

Tags: django

Изучаю Django и стало интересно: а как можно в моделях сделать иерархию категорий, например, как в авито. Создать по нескольку моделей для обозначения категорий по ForeignKey- костыль первозданного вида. Как же можно такое осуществить?

Comment: Не в курсе что там на авито. Иерархия - модель с рекурсивной ссылкой на саму себя. В базе - одна таблица категорий с foreign key со ссылкой на id этой же таблицы (на родительскую категорию). Модель и таблица для категорий ровно одна.

Comment: Можете поподробнее рассказать? Пожалуйста, сейчас очень нуждаюсь в этом знании

Comment: Ну вот тут посмотрите например: https://stackabuse.com/recursive-model-relationships-in-django/ Там иерархия сотрудников организации, поле manager у сотрудника ссылается на вышестоящего сотрудника.

Comment: Ох, как же я вам благодарен. Спасибо вам большое, и с наступающим! :)

Comment: Судя по упоминанию ForeignKey, данные хранятся в реляционной СУБД? Есть _четыре_ способа хранения иерархий в РСУБД: [Иерархические структуры и деревья в SQL](https://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2007/03/4199032). У каждого способа свои достоинства и недостатки.

Comment: Александр, я прочёл статью, что вы предоставили. Спасибо вам за это, способы тоже интересные, но думаю, что в моём случае подойдет именно рекурсивный метод, отсылкой на сам же модель. А если поконкретнее про мои нужды, то мне нужно сделать именно иерархичность товаров